# Unauthorized / token contains no permission when trying to use Microsoft Graph to send email

Tags: email, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

We have a registered application in Azure AD and set up client secrets to run it as a daemon app (with no user interaction). We have the API permissions `Mail.Send` and `User.Read` admin consented for Microsoft Graph API.

My understanding is to use construct a `ConfidentialClientApplication` to get an access token for the registered app, by which I can create a GraphServiceClient. Then I can use the client to send email as a user.

**But I got the following exception saying there's no permission in the token:** (but I did provide a scope for getting permission)

```
Message: The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        request-id: omitted-xxxx-xxx-...31c53
        date: 2020-03-13T23:41:08
ClientRequestId: omitted-xxxx-xxx-...31c57

   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at GraphCallsFromServiceAccount.MyGraphClient.SendEmail(GraphServiceClient graphClient) in C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\GraphCallsFromAccount\MyGraphClient.cs:line 109
```

**Relevant Code:**

```
// create a ConfidentialClientApplication:
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AppClientId)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+ TenantId + "/oauth2/v2.0/token"))
                .WithClientSecret(ClientSecretString)
                .Build();

            var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }; // if changed to "Mail.Send", it throws errors saying invalid scope.
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMg) =>
                    {
                        // add access token to header
                        var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                        requestMg.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.AccessToken);
                    }));

  // send email:
try
            {
                var toAddress = "john_doe@helloworld.com";
                var SenderAddress = "jane_doe@helloworld.com";
                var recipient = new Recipient()
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress()
                    {
                        Name = "John Doe",
                        Address = toAddress,
                    }
                };

                Message email = new Message
                {
                    Body = new ItemBody
                    {
                        Content = "<b>hello world</b>",
                        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    },
                    Subject = "hello world",
                    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>() { recipient },
                };

                Console.WriteLine("hello 2");
                await graphClient.Users["john_doe@helloworld.com"].SendMail(email, false).Request().PostAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ex: " + ex);
            }
```

How do I request the correct permissions put in the access token then? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are acquiring a token as an app,
you are most likely not using application permissions.
You cannot use delegated permissions when running as an app,
as those only apply if running in the context of a user.

You'll need to add the Mail.Send *application permission* on Microsoft Graph API,
and an admin must then consent that.